# CPU speed and cat /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: linux, cpu, proc, cpu-frequency

I use centos 6.4 64. I have old proc - CPU AMD Phenom II X4 810 (HDX810W) 2.6 GHz. However, when I execute the command `cat /proc/cpuinfo` I get the following:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 16
model       : 4
model name  : AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 810 Processor
stepping    : 2
cpu MHz     : 800.000
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
...
```

All four cores have the same speed 800 MHz. How to explain it?

Comment: Note that it is also possible to have [CPU higher than maximum](https://superuser.com/questions/837178/cpu-higher-than-maximum).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the *current* CPU frequency; it can be scaled up and down.

Have a look in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0` (or 1, 2, 3), then the `cpufreq` directory.

Check `cat scaling_governor`.  It is probably `ondemand` (I believe that's the default kernel configuration).  Now check `scaling_available_frequencies`; you'll see a list that for you should start with 2600000.

The kernel will boost the frequency when required.  Try a busy loop, with bash:

```
while (( 1 )); do echo busy; done
```

Let that go and check your frequencies.  They should go up.  If you have a CPU monitor and one of them hits close to 100%, that core will probably be at the max frequency now.